# Find $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ such that $(ax+b)^2(x+c) = 4x^3 + dx^2 + 55x - 100$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, quadratics

How would I find $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ in :

$$(ax+b)^2(x+c) = 4x^3 + dx^2 + 55x - 100$$

I have already worked out that $a=2$, but I may be wrong. I am not sure how to find the values of the other letters.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How did you get $a = 2$?

Comment: @fleablood Hint: $(ax)^2(x)=4$

Comment: @Roskiller  That *isn't* why I asked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f(x) = 4x^3 + dx^2 + 55x - 100 = (ax+b)^2(x+c)$.

It is trivial to see $a = \pm 2$. We will only consider the case $a = 2$. The key of this problem is $f(x)$ contains a squared factor $(ax+b)^2$. This means $f'(x) = 12x^2+2dx+55$  contain $(ax+b)$ as a factor.

Given any two polynomials $g(x), h(x) \in \mathbb{C}[x]$. If you compute their gcd over $\mathbb{C}[x]$ using Euclidean algorithm, the gcd you get will be an expression independent of $x$. It will be a polynomial in coefficients of $g(x)$ and $h(x)$. The most important property of this gcd is

> $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ contains a common factor if and only if this gcd vanishes.

Up to some scaling factor, this gcd is known as the [resultant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant) of the two polynomials. If you throw the command
`Resultant[4*x^3 + d*x^2 + 55*x-100,12*x^2+2*d*x+55,x]` to WA ([wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/)), you will obtain following condition for $d$:

$$D(d) \stackrel{def}{=} 16 d^3 + 121 d^2 - 15840 d - 279280 = 0\tag{*1}$$

Up to scaling factor again, the resultant of a polynomial $f(x)$ and its derivative $f'(x)$ is known as its [discriminant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant). You can also use the command `Discriminant[4*x^3+d*x^2+55*x-100,x]` on WA to derive above condition.

To derive $b$, we will use the fact when you compute the gcd between $f(x)$ and $f'(x)$ using Euclidean algorithm. By the the time you obtain a linear factor, that factor will proportional to $ax + b$. Since

$$36f(x) - (12x+d)f'(x) = (1320-2d^2)x - (55d+3600)$$

we have

$$2 : b = 1320-2d^2 : 55d+3600 \quad\implies\quad
b = B(d) \stackrel{def}{=} \frac{55d+3600}{d^2 - 660}$$

By comparing coefficients of $x^2$ in $4x^3 + dx^2 + 55x - 100 = (ax+b)^2(x+c)$, we obtain following expression for $c$:

$$c = \frac{d}{4} - b = C(d) \stackrel{def}{=} \frac{d}{4} - \frac{55d+3600}{d^2-660}$$

Using these expression of $b$ and $c$, one can use a CAS to verify

$$(2x+B(d))^2(x + C(b)) = f(x) + \frac{25 D(d) (36 d^2x-23760x+d^3+43200)}{4(d^2-660)^3}$$

As one can see, everything comes down to solving the cubic equation $D(d) = 0$.

Numerically, $D(d) = 0$ has a root at $d_0 \approx 34.98939913719146$. This
leads to following approximate solution of the problem:

$$\begin{align}(a,b,c,d) 
&= (a,B(d_0),C(d_0),d_0)\\
&= ( 2,\; 9.790585944043832,-1.043236159745968,\; 34.98939913719146 )\end{align}$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $$(ax+b)^2(x+c)={a}^{2}c{x}^{2}+{a}^{2}{x}^{3}+2\,abcx+2\,ab{x}^{2}+{b}^{2}c+x{b}^{2}=a^2x^3+x^2(a^2c+2ab)+x(2abc+b^2)+b^2c$$

Answer (score 2):

Just do it:

$(ax+b)^2(x+c)$ expands to $(a^2x^2 + 2abx + b^2)(x+c) = a^2x^3  + 2abx^2 + b^2 x + a^2cx^2 + 2abcx + b^2c= a^2x^3 + (2ab + a^2c)x^2 + (b^2 +2abc)x + b^2 c$

So

$a^2x^3 + (2ab + a^2c)x^2 + (b^2 +2abc)x + b^2 c= 4x^3 + dx^2 + 55x - 100$

So you get three sets of equations:

$a^2 = 4$

$2ab + a^2c = d$

$b^2 +2abc=55$

and $b^2c = -100$.

So solve them:

So $a^2 = 4 \implies a = \pm 2$.  Now if $\pm2, b_1, c_1, d_1$ is a solutions set then $\mp2, -b_1,c_1, d_1$ is also a solution set so, wolog, we'll assume $a = 2$. And

$2ab + a^2c = d\implies d =4(b+c)$

$b^2 +2abc=55\implies b^2 + 4cb - 55 = 0 \implies b = \frac {- 4c \pm \sqrt{16c^2 + 220}}{2}= -2c \pm \sqrt{c^2 - 55}$

And finally $b^2c = -100$ means $c(-2c \pm \sqrt{c^2 - 55})^2 = -100$

$c(4c^2 \pm 4\sqrt{c^2 - 55} + c^2 - 55) = -100$

Which I don't envy you solving.

But $c < 0$ (because $cb^2 =-100 < 0$) and$c^2 > 55 $ so $|c|(4c^2 + c^2 - 55) > 100$ so that "$\pm$" must be "$-$"

Comment: Could you please add more detail as to how I would proceed after the last step mentioned? What are the 2 cubics that I have to solve?

Answer (score 0):

You can expand out the left side.  The coefficient of each power of $x$ on the left must match the corresponding coefficient on the right.
But you'll end up solving a cubic equation for $b$, $c$ or $d$.

Answer (score 0):

There are four unknown in $$(ax+b)^2(x+c) = 4x^3 + dx^2 + 55x - 100$$, so by assigning four values to  $x$ and solving the resulting equations you find your unknowns.

For example for $x=0$ we get

$$2bc = - 100$$

For x=1, you get  $$(a+b)^2(1+c) = 4 + d + 55 - 100$$

The rest is simple algebra and you can manage it.

Comment: @achillehui  Thanks for the comment. I have changed my solution.

Answer (score 0):

It cannot be done, assuming these coefficients are supposed to be integers.

You have established that $a$ may be assumed to be $2$, assuming $a$ is positive.

Note that $b^2c=-100$, so $|b|$ is either $1$, $2$, $5$, or $10$. But $b$ cannot be even, or all coeffficients of the right side would be even. And there is that $55$ countering that. So $|b|$ is either $1$ or $5$.

$4x^3+55x-100$ is monotonically increasing with one root. Subtracting a positive multiple of $x^2$ would not change the root count. So $d$ must be positive. Furthermore, the doubled root will be negative and $b>0$. So $b$ itself is $1$ or $5$ (with $c$ being $-100$ or $-4$).

Now it is narrowed down enough to check:
$$(2x+1)^2(x-100)\stackrel{?}{=}4x^3+dx+55x-100$$
$$(2x+5)^2(x-4)\stackrel{?}{=}4x^3+dx+55x-100$$

Expanded, you have:
$$4x^3-396x^2-99x-100\stackrel{?}{=}4x^3+dx+55x-100$$
$$4x^3+4x^2-35x-100\stackrel{?}{=}4x^3+dx+55x-100$$

And in both cases the linear coefficient is not working out to match.

Comment: I agree and a simple way to proceed after you see that b has to be odd is just check the values for b and c that result in the b^2+2abc=55 equation that results from equating coefficients. Neither abs(b)=1 or 5 results in integer solutions for a so it’s done. Either the problem was mis typed or it wasn’t correctly tagged number theory.